# Running an infinite loop in Thonny/Python or RaPi locks up IDE, how can I break out of it without rebooting?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, infinite-loop, thonny

New to python, but this may be an issue with Thonny also.

The code is an infinite loop acting as a timer.

```
While True:
    #Determine if relay needs to turn on off
```

If I have a small number of timer instructions I can still click stop in Thonny and everything works fine, but if I have like 25, thonny completely locks up, can't even close it, but the code is still running fine and the rest of the os works fine. The schedule is a json file loaded into memory.

Can't put a wait in the loop because it is dealing with ms timing, so a half second wait can mess the schedule up.

Is there a better IDE for something like this than Thonny or a good way to stop the code without rebooting?

Haven't done any threadding yet, but if needed I will rewite. 4gb Pi, so memory shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Have you tried killing the job from the terminal?

Comment: Have a bunch of debug logging to console which doesn't seem to work from the terminal unless I missed something.

Comment: Sorry, I mean open a new terminal, find the PID and use the kill command - on your Py script and/or Thronny.

Comment: I will try that next time. Any suggestions to make it so I don't have to kill it every time?

Comment: I’d prob just write the script in vim and run using the terminal, and give Thonny a miss altogether.  Or, if you have the non-server OS on your Pi, use Jupyter.

Comment: Try "Run => Run current script in Terminal" in Thonny.